# HTML/CSS Drag-and-Drop Div Snaps to Incorrect Position Relative to Mouse

Tags: javascript, html, css

### Problem

I have a series of cells in a table that store several individual cards. These cards can be rearranged within a cell or moved between cells by dragging and dropping. However, I am finding that when I pick up my card, it does not track directly from where I clicked it. In other words, if I clicked on the upper-right-most corner, it immediately shifts away from my mouse in an unexpected manner. Even stranger is the fact that it works fine if I have my cards stored outside of a table tag. What does the table do that causes my mouse-shift calculation to be incorrect?

### JSFiddle

Here is a link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0atymsb9/1/

Keep an eye on where you click, and where the div is positioned relative to your mouse. EDIT: It is while you are dragging the card that the visual defect is occurring, but once you place it it's okay.

(The first square is a  within a  (doesn't work right), and the second is simply a div (works well.))

I am following this tutorial: https://htmldom.dev/drag-and-drop-element-in-a-list/

### Code

- JS

```js
// Setup

function setupCards() {
    const cards = document.getElementsByClassName("card");
    const cells = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");

    for (const card of cards) {
        card.classList.add("draggable");
    }

    for (const cell of cells) {
        [].slice.call(cell.querySelectorAll('.draggable')).forEach((item) => {
            item.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDownHandler);
        });
    }

}


// Dragging Logic

let placeholder;
let draggingEle;
let isDraggingStarted = false;
let mouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };

function swap(nodeA, nodeB) {
    const parentA = nodeA.parentNode;
    const siblingA = nodeA.nextSibling === nodeB ? nodeA : nodeA.nextSibling;

    // Move `nodeA` to before the `nodeB`
    nodeB.parentNode.insertBefore(nodeA, nodeB);

    // Move `nodeB` to before the sibling of `nodeA`
    parentA.insertBefore(nodeB, siblingA);
};

function isAbove(nodeA, nodeB) {
    const rectA = nodeA.getBoundingClientRect();
    const rectB = nodeB.getBoundingClientRect();

    return (rectA.top + rectA.height / 2 < rectB.top + rectB.height / 2);
}

// Handlers

const mouseMoveHandler = function (e) {
    // Set position for dragging element
    const draggingRect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();

    if (!isDraggingStarted) {
        isDraggingStarted = true;

        placeholder = document.createElement('div');
        placeholder.classList.add('placeholder');
        draggingEle.parentNode.insertBefore(
            placeholder,
            draggingEle.nextSibling
        );

        placeholder.style.height = `${draggingRect.height}px`;
    }

    draggingEle.style.position = 'absolute';
    draggingEle.style.top = `${e.pageY - mouse.y}px`;
    draggingEle.style.left = `${e.pageX - mouse.x}px`;


    const prevEle = draggingEle.previousElementSibling;
    const nextEle = placeholder.nextElementSibling;

    if (prevEle && isAbove(draggingEle, prevEle)) {
        swap(placeholder, draggingEle);
        swap(placeholder, prevEle);
        return;
    }

    if (nextEle && isAbove(nextEle, draggingEle)) {
        swap(nextEle, placeholder);
        swap(nextEle, draggingEle);
    }
};

const mouseUpHandler = function () {
    placeholder && placeholder.parentNode.removeChild(placeholder);
    isDraggingStarted = false;

    // Remove the position styles
    draggingEle.style.removeProperty('top');
    draggingEle.style.removeProperty('left');
    draggingEle.style.removeProperty('position');

    mouse.x = null;
    mouse.y = null;
    draggingEle = null;

    // Remove the handlers of `mousemove` and `mouseup`
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
};

function mouseDownHandler(e) {
    draggingEle = e.target;

    const rect = draggingEle.getBoundingClientRect();
    mouse.x = e.pageX - rect.left;
    mouse.y = e.pageY - rect.top;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMoveHandler);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpHandler);
}

// Main

function main() {
    setupCards()

}

main()
```

- HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <td>
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="card">Test 1</div>
                <div class="card">Test 2</div>
                <div class="card">Test 3</div>
                <div class="card">Test 4</div>
                <div class="card">Test 5</div>
                <div class="card">Test 6</div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </table>

    <div class="cell">
        <div class="card">Test 1</div>
        <div class="card">Test 2</div>
        <div class="card">Test 3</div>
        <div class="card">Test 4</div>
        <div class="card">Test 5</div>
        <div class="card">Test 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

- CSS

```css
td {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    position: relative;
}

.cell {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;

    background-color: aquamarine;
    border: 1px solid black;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card {
    background-color: darkgreen;
    color: white;

    width: 4em;
    height: 1em;

    text-align: center;
}


/* Dragging */

.draggable {
    user-select: none;
}
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not exactly with the `table` tag. I found two ways to solve this problem.

**First solution that change the HTML**: Simply comment or remove the `<td>` tag as follows

```
<body>
    <table>
        <!-- <td> --> <!--comment or remove this line-->
            <div class="cell">
                <div class="card">Test 1</div>
                <div class="card">Test 2</div>
                <div class="card">Test 3</div>
                <div class="card">Test 4</div>
                <div class="card">Test 5</div>
                <div class="card">Test 6</div>
            </div>
        <!-- </td>--> <!--comment or remove this line-->
    </table>

    <div class="cell">
        <div class="card">Test 1</div>
        <div class="card">Test 2</div>
        <div class="card">Test 3</div>
        <div class="card">Test 4</div>
        <div class="card">Test 5</div>
        <div class="card">Test 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Second solution that change the CSS**:
This solution is better because you do not need to remove anything in the HTML (maybe is what you want), i.e, do not need to remove `<td>` or `<table>` tags. In the CSS file change the `position: relative` to `position: center` as follows

```
td {
    width: 8em;
    height: 8em;
    position: center; /*change from relative to center*/
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! Just out of curiosity, do you know why there would be a difference between the two examples? It seems arbitrary to me that one would work fine but the other would not.